# save the transient instance before flushing while saving object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to save the MotoPayment object. But i have to check the customer with code already exists or not before saving motopayment object.

```
public class MotoPaymentOrder extends BaseDocument {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER")
    private Customer customer;

    @Column(name = "AMOUNT")
    private Double amount = Double.valueOf(0);

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PAYMENTSTATUS")
    protected SystemTypeLookupData status ;

    @Column(name = "PNRNO")
    private String pnrNo;

    @Column(name = "RESERVATIONNO")
    private String reservationNo;

}
```

**controller method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/motopaymnetorder", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody public MotoPaymentOrder create(@RequestBody MotoPaymentOrder domain){
        prepareCustomer(domain.getCustomer());
        return (MotoPaymentOrder) baseDocumentService.saveDocument(domain);
    }
```

The below method is used to check the customer with code exists or not otherwise save customer object.

```
public void prepareCustomer(Customer customer){
        Customer existingCustomer = (Customer) appService.findOneWhere("WHERE o.code = '"+customer.getCode()+"'",Customer.class);
        if(existingCustomer==null){
            customer.setType(ApplicationConstants.CustomerType.Person);

            PersonCustomer personCustomer = new PersonCustomer();
            personCustomer.setEmail(customer.getCustomerEmail());
            personCustomer.setFirstName(customer.getPersonCustomer().getFirstName());
            personCustomer.setLastName(customer.getPersonCustomer().getLastName());
            personCustomer.setCustomer(customer);

            customer.setPersonCustomer(personCustomer);


        }
    }
```

I'm getting below exception while saving MotoPaymentOrder object:

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.erp.hospitality.domain.MotoPaymentOrder.customer -> com.erp.core.domain.common.Customer
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$8.noCascade(CascadingActions.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: Good read. https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/03/05/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/

Comment: try persisting transient child object manually and then set it to parent object.

Answer (score 2):

See here
[save the transient instance before flushing in SpringBoot 2.0.4 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52020024/save-the-transient-instance-before-flushing-in-springboot-2-0-4-app)

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER")
private Customer customer;
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for a `MotoPaymentOrder`, the associated `Customer` is not persisted, the `JPA` will should persist it, which is not implemented by your approach. You can use `CascadeType.REFRESH` to tell hibernate what to do with your entity, if that is not already persisted.

```java
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER")
private Customer customer;
```